# Issues with dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dialog box that needs to show when a user clicks on submit. The user then has to either accept the terms of the usage of our resources.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            var Form;
            $("#confirm").dialog({
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'No': function() { // No works (since I only need to close the box)
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    'Yes': function() { // This is not working. The button just keeps me on the same page with no submission
                        Form.submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    $("#acceptform").submit(function() { // This is the form that a user has to submit before the dialog box appears
        Form = this;
        $('#confirm').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

If there are any other things need to better ask this question please let me know.

Comment: The issue is in my code comments, sorry! The issue is that Yes button is not submitting the form. It keeps me on the same page / dialog box

Comment: I see `var Form;` but I never see it get set to anything until after submitting.

Comment: I thought setting it at the second part of the script sets the var form? Form = this. this is the #acceptform identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key to solution is  identify if Confirm box already Open... if its already open then Form is being submitted then form need to continue...

In yur case when you do form.submit .. the code agaiin goes to submit handler and returns false... so form submition fails.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dnFTw/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var FORM=$("#acceptform");
        $(function() {
            $("#confirm").dialog({
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'No': function() { // No works (since I only need to close the box)
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        FORM.data("confirmProgress",false);
                    },
                    'Yes': function() { // This is not working. The button just keeps me on the same page with no submission
                        FORM.submit();
                        FORM.data("confirmProgress",false);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    FORM.submit(function() { // This is the form that a user has to submit before the dialog box appears

        if(!$(this).data("confirmProgress")){

            $(this).data("confirmProgress",true);
            $('#confirm').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }else{
           return true;
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't submit the form. The "Yes" button is still action-less

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dnFTw/ Working example... What error do you get ... check javascript console..Updated answer with Workign demo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dnFTw/1/ updated working demo with first there is small bug.. confirm box appears only once.. (if clicked cancel)..

Comment: Your absolutely wonderful! Thanks a million. I can't upvote you since I have less then 15 points